# Section and subsection numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

I'm new to LATEX language and now a have a problem with section and subsection numbering. 
I want to make my text look like this:

**1. Sun**

**1.1 Moon**

**2. Bed**

I was tried to figure out how to make it, but it doesn't work for me.
This is my code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\section{Sun}
\subsection{Moon}
\section{Bed}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the appropriate counter to the third required argument of `\titleformat`.  Currently you just have written `{}` instead of e.g. `{\thesection}`.  Here is a complete example, with left alignment rather than centering:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filright}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries\filright}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Sun}
\subsection{Moon}
\section{Bed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but you may omit `\filright` (and use the `hang` format for both sectioning levels).

Comment: @lockstep indeed - the user's needs are quite clear, so I left the `\filright` so it could easily be switched back to the centering version.